# jdownload resume supported links while downliad dir protected

Tags: joomla2.5

i use jdownloads
i have a collection which is rare and for now iam protecting my download area which user downloads premium file via php , but here is the problem that my premium user which for now access the links but the links are not resume supported , i dont want my users find out the exact files location and i want them to download resume supported links for their download session , any suggestion?

if we disable the download dir protection one premium user  may share the link and everyone may download the file ... so i need protection(download using php) and resume supported links
 ???

Comment: It is hard to understand your question, I think you should try to reformulate it. You might want to show some bits of code which are relevant to your problem.

Comment: i asked jdownloads developer they told me this may be available in the next release  of jdownloads 2